# Ubuntu 10.04 shutdown on Bigbluebutton installation

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am facing a problem with Bigbluebutton on two systems . I have bigbluebutton version 0.8 installed on two systems .My problem is,Both systems are stopped working(sHUTDOWN ) after one  or 2 days .

One of my ubuntu server is hosted on Amazone EC2 .

I don't know weather this problem is with server or BBB itself .

Please help me two figure out .

I am using the BBB v0.8

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to logged on server  this is not the first time .Hosting company will start the server soon

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton and I can say there is no code in BigBlueButton that, based on our experience of over four years of development, is going to shutdown a Linux server (i.e. sudo shutdown -h now).

The problem is with your server environment.